# In a Makefile do we use 'prefix' or 'PREFIX'?

Tags: linux, makefile, prefix

Currently in my `Makefile` I have:

```
prefix ?= /usr/local
```

So that I can override `prefix` value when calling `make`, like in the following:

```
make prefix="/new_path"
```

My question is: does a convention exist for naming this variable inside a Makefile, especially do I have to call it `prefix` or `PREFIX`?

This matter since lower or upper case matters in this situation!

Note that I *do not* use `autotools`, just a "simple" `Makefile`

Comment: I don't know if there's a definitive answer. My own preference is to use all caps when the variable is something that I document as being overridable by the user and to use lower case when it's something internal that's not to be messed with.

Comment: @noufal Thanks for the explanation. So I will make use in my case of PREFIX (since can be overridden). It's a pitty that i've not found a doc about these convention (even if they are not totally fixed)...

Comment: That's what *I'd* do but it's really my own convention.

Comment: Wow, I'm astonished this 5+ years old question still doesn't have a definite answer.

Answer (score 7):

The [variables for installation directories](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Directory-Variables) section of the GNU make manual discusses `prefix`.

I believe the autotools use a similarly-cased `prefix` variable/`configure` flag.

Compare to [`DESTDIR`](https://www.gnu.org/prep/standards/html_node/DESTDIR.html) however.

Comment: @ethan thanks for the doc but I already read it without any clue about my specific concern...

Comment: The prevailing consensus (between GNU make and the autotools) is to use `prefix`. I added the bit about `DESTDIR` just to indicate that they do also use `ALL_CAP` variables and I don't know why specifically. In the absence of a consensus on `PREFIX` somewhere else (bsd, etc.) this would seem to indicate that you should use `prefix`. Which is why I posted the information. I can't give a more concrete/definitive answer than that.